# Class or View isn't updating

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Basically, I have a class which fetches profile info from Firestore, but when I edit the profile and submit the changes and return to the profile view, the information isn't updated, but it is updated within Firestone, so I have to close the app and relaunch it for it to update within the app. I'm assuming my issue is because I am not recalling the class or the view isn't being updated? Here is my code for the profile view, and the class I call to fetch the data from Firestore.

ProfileView.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore


struct ProfileView: View {
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    @ObservedObject private var user = MainUserDataModel() //pulls user data from firebase (located in fetchUserData.swift) works like: user.currentUser?.uid ?? ""
    @State private var firstName = ""
    @State private var lastName = ""
    @State private var email = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("img")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding()
            Text("\(firstName) \(lastName)")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
        
            Text("\(email)")
                .font(.caption)
                .padding(5)
            NavigationLink("Edit Profile", destination: EditProfile())
                .foregroundColor(Color.pink)
            Form {
            
            }
            
        }
        .task {
            firstName = user.currentUser?.firstName ?? ""
            lastName = user.currentUser?.lastName ?? ""
            email = user.currentUser?.email ?? ""
            
        }
        //.navigationTitle("Profile")
    }
}


struct ProfileView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ProfileView()
    }
}
```

fetchUserData.swift

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

struct User {
    let firstName, lastName, uid, email: String
    
}

class MainUserDataModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    @Published var currentUser: User?

    init() {
        fetchUserData()
    }

    private func fetchUserData() {
        let auth = Auth.auth()
        guard let uid = auth.currentUser?.uid else { return }

        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).getDocument { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                self.errorMessage = "Failed to fetch current user: \(error)"
                print("Failed to fetch current user:", error)
                return
            }

            guard let data = snapshot?.data() else {
                self.errorMessage = "No data found"
                return

            }
            let firstName = data["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
            let lastName = data["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
            let uid = data["uid"] as? String ?? ""
            let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
            self.currentUser = User(firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, uid: uid, email: email)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Start by checking/printing data["firstName"] etc and see if you are getting the correct data from firestore itself. This can be a problem if you have caching enabled for firestore. And let us know your findings and we can go from there.

Comment: I added a "print(firstName") under line 42 in the fetchUserData, its actually only calling that function on the initial start up, it does not call after I update the user info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting your `@State` variables before the `fetchUserData` has completed. It would be cleaner to remove the `@State` variables altogether and just rely on the `@Published` values from your `MainUserDataModel`:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    @ObservedObject private var user = MainUserDataModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("mank")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding()
            if let currentUser = user.currentUser {
                Text("\(currentUser.firstName) \(currentUser.lastName)")
                  .fontWeight(.bold)
                Text("\(currentUser.email)")
                  .font(.caption)
                  .padding(5)
                NavigationLink("Edit Profile", destination: EditProfile())
                .foregroundColor(Color.pink)
            } else {
               //Display a loading indicator
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use your previous strategy of providing default values:

```
struct ProfileView: View {
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    @ObservedObject private var user = MainUserDataModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("mank")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .padding()
            Text("\(user.currentUser?.firstName ?? "") \(user.currentUser?.lastName ?? "")")
                  .fontWeight(.bold)
            Text("\(user.currentUser?.email ?? "")")
                  .font(.caption)
                  .padding(5)
            NavigationLink("Edit Profile", destination: EditProfile())
                .foregroundColor(Color.pink)
        }
    }
}
```

If instead, you *really* need the `@State` variables, you shouldn't set them until your `MainUserDataModel` loads the data -- you can use `onReceive` and watch for changes to the `currentUser` publisher.

Comment: Thanks for the reply although this did not work I noticed that my fetchUserData function is only being called on the initial start up, how can I "recall" this function i.e with a button to call it on a click or something along those lines, I could just add that to my save changes button

Comment: You could use a Button and set the action to call fetchUserData -- (`user.fetchUserData()`). But, maybe just use a Firestore function that actively returns changes? like `addSnapshotListener` instead of `getDocument`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: user.fetchUserData() works great. I knew it was a simple fix but I just couldn't think of it being that easy. Thanks for your help!